# Re-write the method with Java 8 lambda

Tags: lambda, java-8

I have written a small method which recive a string and compare the string with an `enum` property. If it is matched I am returning the specific `enum`. Here is the working code.

```
   public static ScreenPlay getAct(String text) {
        ScreenPlay act = null;
        for (ScreenPlay aAct : ScreenPlay.values()) {
            for (String code : aAct.code) {
                if (StringUtils.contains(text, code)) {
                    act = aAct;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (act != null) {
                break;
            }
        }
        return act;
    }
```

I am wondering if these could be re-written using the lambda? Any help would be greatly appriciated.

**UPDATE:**

Below is my try:

```
Arrays.stream(ScreenPlay.values())
                .forEach(a -> a.code.stream()
.filter(code -> StringUtils.contains(text, code))); // not sure how to get Optional of ScreenPlay
```

Comment: _I am wondering if these could be re-written using the lambda?_ : **Yes**

Comment: @coder-croc could you help me out (rewrite the method)?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Read some documentation about streams and lambdas? Tried something based on that documentation?

Comment: @JBNizet I tried to use stream on `ScreenPlay.values()` and `aAct.code` and tried to filter out the particular `aAct`. But I am not sure how could I get an `Optional` of `ScreenPlay` when the particular criteria matched. The code I tried is not useful to post in anyway. So I did not put it in the question

Comment: Post what you tried in the question, so that we can fix/improve it. In addition to filter(), look into findFirst() and anyMatch().

Comment: @JBNizet I have updated my code. Maybe now you could give the proper direction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

forEach is a terminal operation, returning nothing. What you want as a result is an Optional: the first ScreenPlay (if it exists) which matches a predicate.

So the code should be

```
Optional<ScreenPlay> result = stream.filter(screenPlay -> shouldAccept(screenPlay, text))
                                    .findFirst();
```

Now, you want to implement the `shouldAccept(ScreenPlay, String text)` method. This method should return true if the screenPlay has at least one code containing the text (or vice-versa, depending on what your `StringUtils.contains()` method does.

There is a stream method for that: anyMatch():

```
boolean shouldAccept(ScreenPlay screenPlay, String text) {
    return screenPlay.codes.stream().anyMatch(code -> StringUtils.contains(text, code));
}
```

Of course, you can inline this method if you want to. Note how good naming (screenPlay instead of aAct, codes instead of code, code instead of act) makes the code much more readable.

Comment: I think ScreenPlay is an enum in that case we can simply pass text as codes will be accessible in method. `shouldAccept(String text)` should be declared in ScreenPlay..

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for `filter` along with `findFirst`:

```
Optional<ScreenPlay> act = Arrays.stream(ScreenPlay.values())
                       .filter(aAct -> Arrays.stream(aAct.code)
                             .anyMatch(code -> StringUtils.contains(text, code))                           
                       .findFirst();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I am looking for `Optional<ScreenPlay>` not `Optional<String>`

Comment: @DebmalyaBiswas if `aAct.code` is not an array then make sure to use `aAct.code.stream().anyMatch(code -> StringUtils.contains(text, code))` instead.